# Unable to start elasticsearch 2.2.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have installed elasticsearch 2.2.0 and it worked fine for a week, but now it didn't start. I have set both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME. I use java version 1.8 (i.e., jdk1.8.0_201 and jre1.8.0_202). When I try to start the elasticsearch.bat it terminates with a error message of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLineParser
Likely root cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:241)
    at 
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

But no logs has been generated.

Comment: which OS u are using?

Comment: windows 10. The java api works fine now